# Essential spectrum of a projection

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

For any $T\in B(H)$, the essential spectrum $\sigma_e(T)$ of $T$ is a subset of the spectrum $\sigma(T)$ of $T$; namely, the $\lambda$ such that $\lambda-T$ is not [Fredholm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_operator).

If $P$ is a projection, we have $\sigma_e(P)\subset \sigma(P)=\{0,1\}$. My question is whether $\sigma_e(P)$ can be $\{0\}$,$\{1\}$,$\{0,1\}$.

Can we find some concrete examples to show that the above three cases can happen?

Comment: Please define essential spectrum.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_spectrum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

1. a projection onto a finite dimensional space,
2. a projection onto a finite co-dimensional space,
3. a projection not of the above types.

Comment: But I saw another conclusion: the essential numerical range  $W_e(P)$ of $P$ is $[0,1]$ and $cov(\sigma_e(P))=W_e(P)$, If $\sigma_e(P))=\{0\}$, $W_e(P)\neq [0,1]$.

Comment: $\sigma_e(P)=\{0\}$ iff $P$ is compact iff $W_e(P)=\{0\}$.